# gPrinter label printing from website?

Tags: css, printing, barcode

I have been meddling with this for the past three days and there is no on-line documentation regarding this. When I print the barcode generated by php along with some other text as shown below in the first image, printing goes horribly wrong. The whole design is generated from the server side and sent to chrome. When I print, the printing is either off, or totally different, tiny or off-label. I tinkered with the printer settings, setting the page size to the size of the label, no luck. Each time, something is off.
Here is how the printed copy looks-

[image]

Here is how the div containing the printable part looks (used a js library to set the printable area which is working fine)-

[image]

And finally here is how it looks when I change the browser rendering to print from screen-

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code-

```
<div id='printArr'>
    <p class='card-title' style='text-align:center;margin:2px 0 -10px 0;font-size:11px'><strong>$mvalue->product_name</strong></p>
    <div class='card-body text-center'>
        <p class='card-title chead' style='text-align:center'>$mvalue->strength &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; $mvalue->form</p>
        <img class='' src='$base/assets/images/barcode/$mvalue->batch_no.png' alt='Card image'>
        <div class='container'>
            <p style='text-align:center;margin:3px 0 -5px 0;font-size:10px'>EXP:$mvalue->expire_date</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@media print{
    #printArr {
    width: 1.5in;
    height: 1.0in;
    box-shadow: none !IMPORTANT;
    border-radius: 0 !IMPORTANT;
    margin: 0;
}
.chead{
    font-size: 9px !IMPORTANT;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#printArr img {
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    max-height: .8in
}    
}
#printArr img {
   max-width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Am I going at it complete the wrong way?
Printer model- gPrinter GP3120TU
Page size: 1.5 inch by 1 inch